# React native: how can I extend this timer through an alert?

Tags: javascript, react-native

I am new to react native. I have a countdown timer (currently set to 5 seconds) and when the time is up, I want an alert which gives the user an option to restart the timer. There will be other elements in the screen so I don't necessarily want a "refresh" (for example, if the user inputted some text, I don't want that to go away when the timer is extended).

The alert pops up when the time is up, but I'm not sure how to reset the timer via the alert button.

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
  StyleSheet,
  TouchableOpacity,
  Text,
  View,
  TextInput,
  Alert,
} from 'react-native'
import CountDown from 'react-native-countdown-component';

export default class Payment extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      timer: 5,
    };
  }
  
  timesUp = () => {
    Alert.alert(
      "Time's Up!",
      "How can we help you?",
      [
        { 
          text: "Extend Timer",
          // I want to restart the timer here
          onPress: this.setState(newTime => ({ timer: 5})) },
        {
          text: "Cancel",
          onPress: () => console.log("Cancel Pressed") },
      ],
      { cancelable: false }
    );
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View>
        <View style={{ marginTop: 20}}>
          <CountDown
            size={15}
            until={this.state.timer}
            onFinish={this.timesUp}
            digitStyle={{backgroundColor: '#FFF', borderWidth: 2, borderColor: '#cccccc'}}
            digitTxtStyle={{color: 'black'}}
            separatorStyle={{color: 'black'}}
            timeToShow={['M', 'S']}
            timeLabels={{m: null, s: null}}
            showSeparator
          />
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`react-native-countdown-component` provides an `id` props to determine if you want to reset the timer. https://github.com/talalmajali/react-native-countdown-component#props

You can just reset the `id` when times out.

```
onPress: () => this.setState({ timerId: newTimerId })


<CountDown id={this.state.timerId} />
```

Comment: This works for me if the values of timerId and newTimerId are different, but not if they are the same. I currently have both timerId and newTimerId as 5

Comment: you have to set different `id`, you need to create another state `timerId`, 5 is just your timer countdown, while `timerId` is the id for the timer, you will reset your timer if the `timerId` change. So basically you will have 2 things in your state

Comment: Got it, thanks! With your solution, I ran into the issue where I couldn't restart the timer for the third time. `onPress: () => this.setState({ timerId : !this.state.timerId }) }` works well for me

Comment: I will recommend to use a random id or an incremental id instead, for example `onPress: () => this.setState(previousState => ({ timerId : ++previousState.timerId })) }`, Glad it's helped

Answer (score 1):

Please use setTimeout(function() {}, Time in Milli seconds). 
Its a native javascript function used to trigger a function after certain time.